# dynamic Appointment scheduler

Tags: database, synchronization

I have two sheets called "Scheduler" and "2018".

My dynamic date is in m3 of Scheduler and I want to type appointment descriptions in m4:m40 and sync the information on 2018 in columns where the rows have the dates on them from Jan 1 - Dec 31.

Example:  When 1/1/2018 shows in m3 and I type something in m4, I want it to be stored on 2018 in column a underneath the date 1/1/2018.  When the date in m3 changes to 1/2/2018, and type in m4 a new appointment description and have it store the information in column b.

I watched a tutorial on how to do this in Excel, but after trying to use AI to help with the coding I thought I'd come ask here.

The original tutorial I watched for excel is here:  https://youtu.be/IWlCloFiWw4?feature=shared

Can anyone help me with the code?

I tried a version of the code, but when I tried to type in Scheduler m4 it doesn't show up on 2018.